# Update from api level 30 to level 31 for google play, using ionic

Tags: api, compilation, apk, ionic4

My ionic info
[this is my ionic info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrqNM.png)

[This my config.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygUWx.png)

I am using gradle 7.6 and java jdk 8u341
When i generate the level 30 apk it works correctly, when i generate the level 31 or 32 apk, it compiles normally, but does not open the app when installed on the device, but when running it shows the message "the application has a bug" and closes by itself. I can't open the app.

I have sdks 30, 31 and 32 installed, and sdk build-tools 28.0.3, 29.0.2 and 29.0.3 installed

To compile, I already corrected the "android:exported" in activities, services and broadcasts.

Help-me plesase!!!

I need update the level of the apk for 31 or 32, for send to google play.

Comment: What is "it" in "it says..." and what exactly is the error message and where is it shown?

Comment: @Pierre - "it says" means that, the application installs normally on the device, but when running it shows the message "the application has a bug" and closes by itself. I can't open the app.

Thanks for help!!!